# Effect of running randomness function at exactly same time each day

Tags: python, random

I have a cron job that runs a Python script with a call to the random package.

I believe, by default, the seed of a randomness call is the timestamp.

Given an approximately equal time delta between the daily runs, will this affect the randomness of the output?

Comment: "approximately equal time" doesn't mean exactly the same, which probably has a significant impact on how `random` responds. Additionally, when you say the timestamp, is that referring to the time portion of the current date, or an indicator of the current moment (e.g. milliseconds since the epoch)? The latter will be steadily increasing with the date, and should be significantly different from the previous date's, randomness-wise.

Comment: Are you making the seed?

Comment: `timestamp` should include date information since it is an offset from some reference date e.g. _milliseconds since the beginning of the epoc_. Even if increases the time delta will be relatively equal. FYI: the Python `random` library makes a note that it is a pseudo-random number generator. One thing about pseudo-RNGs is that it is easy to find congruencies in output, which is what my question is about.

Comment: @PeterWood: I'm not making seed, which is why I asked about how it works by default.

Comment: Your operating system may use `urandom` as a seed. See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.seed)

Comment: Noted. Since the implementation I have in mind ran on a UNIX-like system then it must have been just chance that the output was odd. Thanks!

Comment: What was odd about the output?

Comment: The script involved pairings from a set. After five runs, I observed that one item was paired with two other items across all five runs, which is more improbable than chance. Since the script was run by a cron job that ran at the same time each week (actually), I was wondering whether there was an obvious problem with the RNG.